# ValueError: X has 40 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 32 features as input

Tags: machine-learning, python, jupyter

```
X = data.drop('Price_euros', axis=1)
y = data['Price_euros']

!pip install sklearn

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape

model training
def model_acc(model):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print(str(model)+ ' --> ' +str(acc))

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
model_acc(lr)

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lasso = Lasso()
model_acc(lasso)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model_acc(dt)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
model_acc(rf)



from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


parameters = {'n_estimators':[10, 50, 100],
              'criterion':['squared_error','absolute_error','poisson']}

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=parameters)

grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_model = grid_fit.best_estimator_

best_model.score(X_test, y_test)
X_test.columns

import pickle
with open('predictor.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(best_model, file)
pred_value = best_model.predict([[8, 1.3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
pred_value
```